# Android AlertDialog input as an Integer

Tags: android, android-studio, integer, android-alertdialog, numberformatexception

I have an AlertDialog where the user needs to type a number between 1-24 and I stor that for later use. Now to store the number input as an integer I do this:

```
                final EditText userInput = (EditText) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.editTextDialogUserInput);
                String test = userInput.getText().toString();
                int testNumber;
                try {testNumber = Integer.parseInt(test); }
                catch (NumberFormatException e) { testNumber = 0;}
```

Now when testing it seems that whatever number I use as input in the dialog window, it always returns 0, even if it was just a normal number. What can I do that I don't get a NumberFormatException?

EDIT:
After further testing I found that whatever I give as input on my emulator, I always get an empty string.

Comment: your code snippet seems fine, you have tried to debug your code? maybe the problem is somewhere else ?

Comment: could you please log the value of                 String test = userInput.getText().toString();
and insure that your are getting the right text from the input? i think that you are getting an empty text "" witch result of NumberFormatException, that's why you are getting always 0/

Comment: Anis, I think you're right. When I do this: `Log.d("TEST", String.valueOf(finalTestNumber) + test);` it gives this as output: `D/TEST: 0`. Is there any way I can work around this so that I don't get an empty string?

Answer (score 1):

```
testNumber = Integer.parseInt(test.trim());
```

Replace with this, it will be fixed.

**.trim()** removes extra spaces.